# HTML Injection on a web page that does not accept data entry?

Tags: security, xss, html-injections

Can HTML Injection or XSS Injection be done on a web page that does not accept data entry (search, username, password, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [DOM-Based XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/DOM_Based_XSS) vulnerability does not need a REST endpoint to even exist. The attack goes directly to the DOM model of the web page. Actually one of the most troublesome versions of XSS out there.

Comment: So what about HTML Injection?

Comment: If XSS is possible, then HTML injection too.